# Evaluate $\lim _{x\to \infty }\left(\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x}}-\sqrt{x-\sqrt{x}}\right)$

Tags: calculus, limits

Need help calculating this :

$\lim _{x\to \infty }\left(\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x}}-\sqrt{x-\sqrt{x}}\right)
$

Thanks!

Comment: You may have a look here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1929548/limit-of-a-n-sqrtn22-sqrtn21-as-n→∞/1929555?noredirect=1#comment3961434_1929555 to get an idea.

Comment: There are several ways to do it. Could you explain what you already tried ? This will help us to help you.

Comment: Actually I have no idea where to start.. I need only one short way if it is possible from you to help me.

Answer (score 8):

We get that
\begin{align*}
\sqrt{x + \sqrt{x}} - \sqrt{x - \sqrt{x}} &= \frac{(\sqrt{x + \sqrt{x}} - \sqrt{x - \sqrt{x}})(\sqrt{x + \sqrt{x}} + \sqrt{x - \sqrt{x}})}{\sqrt{x + \sqrt{x}} + \sqrt{x - \sqrt{x}}} \\
&= \frac{2\sqrt x}{\sqrt{x + \sqrt{x}} + \sqrt{x - \sqrt{x}}} \\
&= \frac{2}{\sqrt{1 + \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}} + \sqrt{1 - \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}}} \\
& \overset{x \to \infty}{\to} \frac{2}{1 + 1} = 1
\end{align*}
since $\sqrt{1 + \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}} \to 1$ and $\sqrt{1 - \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}} \to 1$ for $x \to \infty$. I hope it helps you :)

Comment: Amazing!!!!!! Thank you very much !

Answer (score 4):

Set $x=1/t^2$, with $t>0$. Then the limit becomes
$$
\lim_{t\to0^+}\frac{\sqrt{1+t}-\sqrt{1-t}}{t}=
\lim_{t\to0^+}\frac{(1+\frac12t+o(t))-(1-\frac12t+o(t))}{t}
$$